# How do I publish to <me>.github.com?

Tags: git, branch, github

I've read the [guide](http://pages.github.com/), which tells you to do the following:

1. create a .github.com repository
2. check it out to `path/to/repo`
3. cd /path/to/repo
4. git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
5. rm .git/index
6. git clean -fdx
7. echo "My GitHub Page" > index.html
8. git add .
9. git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
10. git push origin gh-pages

I've done that. And the page shows up.  Then I moved to a different computer and checked out the repository again. Now I have a "`master`" branch in my local, but no "`gh-pages`."  And following steps 3-6 above leaves me with no files in that branch.  How do I get the files from "`master`" into the branch that will publish to GitHub?

I tried `git checkout master && git push origin gh-pages` but that yields

```
error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push to 'git@github.com:<me>/<me>.github.com.git'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently subsequent pushes to "`origin master`" actually do the trick! It's not documented in the guide, though.

Comment: The reason is that the @gh-pages branch is only required for existing projects. If your project is called <me>.github.com (that is, you can find it at http://github.com/<me>/<me>.github.com/tree/master), then the master branch works!

Comment: Found this question via Google.  This helped me, thanks.  I used the "generate project page" link and it created the index.html in my repository, but it was not published until I did a subsequent push with a minor edit of the page.

Answer (score 4):

As Gaius says, you are following the directions for 'Project Pages', but you are not trying to create a project page, you are trying to create a user page.  Creating a user page is much easier - you just create a '.github.com' repository then push your website files to it's master branch, like you would any other normal project.

The instructions you are trying to follow are for adding a parallel branch containing website files to an already existing project.  We don't want to make you add a 'website' subdirectory or something to your project, so instead we have you create a completely new branch and push your website to that unrelated branch - thus the Git trickery there.

Answer (score 3):

To work on a branch of a fresh remote repository checkout you will first need to create the branch locally. Here is an example for a “`gh-pages`” branch:

```
git checkout --track -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages
```

More details in this article ["Migrating project websites to github pages"](http://drnicwilliams.com/2008/12/21/migrating-project-websites-to-github-pages-with-sake-tasks-new-websites-with-jekyll_generator/)

Comment: I don't think that the gh-pages branch exists remotely or locally.  I get "git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing.  Did you intend to checkout 'origin/gh-pages' which can not be resolved as commit?"

Comment: Strange, in a new gitHub repos, gh-pages does exist from its creation. Since a git clone does bring only remote branches, the checkout --track is needed to make a local branch.